# Sublime Text 3 java linter shows errors for imports

Tags: java, sublimetext3, javac, sublimelinter

when using an external package like the mongo-db driver SublimeLinter-javac will highlight all the symbols as errors and complain that the package cannot be found.

Compiling with javac works though.

How can I get the linter to understand external packages?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add all the libraries that you would like linted to the default folder on OSX for external Java libraries (/Library/Java/Extensions).

If you don't want to do that you can also create a sublime project and add a custom classpath for the sublime linter that includes the libraries.

projects.sublime-project file

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "SublimeLinter":
    {

    }
}
```